# Distance between Multivariate Distributions

Tags: python, statistics

I have a dataset containing three features: gender, height and weight. I would like to find the distance between bivariate distribution of height and weight for males and bivariate distribution of height and weight for females. For calculating the distance between univariate distributions, I found Kolmogorov-Smirnov test to be a good choice, but I've read that it can't be easily applied for multivariate distributions.

Are there any built-in functions in Python, which return the distance of multivariate distributions based on some reliable distance metrics?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kstest.html

Comment: [KL divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) is what you should be looking into. its available in [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.entropy.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the Malahanobis distance. You can find everything you need to know [here](https://www.machinelearningplus.com/statistics/mahalanobis-distance/)